# Problem With Showing src value in text input box from custom dropdown option with php and js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a selection of images that are in a file along with a data base that I use to get the url for each image. I have a custom dropdown option that displays all the images and a text box that I want to later work as a search option. When A image is selected in the dropdown I want the text box value to display that images src value. However it is not working. here is my code:

```js
function Findimage() {
  var Clickedimage = event.target.getAttribute('src');
  $("#imglookupbox").val(Clickedimage);
}
```

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 30px;
  float: left;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.dropdown-menu li {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
}

.dropdown-menu li:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#imglookupbox:focus+.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="imglookupbox" type="text" value="" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
<div class="dropdown">
  <ul id="Imageoptions" class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <img onclick='Findimage()' class='Img_Selection' src="DataBaseSetup/Images/ImageName" alt="no Image">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The code works when not in the `ul` element but it needs to be in it to make the dropdown effect work. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If the problem is entirely client-side, can you provide a [mcve] of only client-side code which demonstrates the problem?  Additionally, what debugging have you done?  Are there any errors in the browser's development console?  When you use the browser's script debugger, is the `Findimage` function invoked?  What specifically happens?

Comment: @David I Change my example to be more client-side. And from what I see when looking in the browser there is no errors. I'm new to website development and am learning as I go.

Comment: The code shown is working as expected.  I'm afraid we're going to need an example of the problem or more specific debugging information about the problem.  If you're not familiar with how to use your browser's debugging tools, now is a great time to get started.

Comment: @David I have coped this code from here and it still dose not work witch makes me think it could be with the styles in my CSS. I'm going to add the drop down styles to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the show/hide logic based on `:focus` in the CSS is happening *before* the click event in JS.  That is, as soon as focus leaves the input, the menu is hiding.  This happens immediately (imperceptably) before the click, so you're not actually clicking on the menu item.

One alternative could be to move the show/hide logic to JavaScript instead.  You can hide the menu when clicking on it, or when clicking away from the input.  For example:

```js
function Findimage() {
  var Clickedimage = event.target.getAttribute('src');
  $("#imglookupbox").val(Clickedimage);
  $('#imglookupbox + .dropdown .dropdown-menu').hide();
  event.stopPropagation();
}

$('#imglookupbox').on('focus', function (e) {
  $('#imglookupbox + .dropdown .dropdown-menu').show();
});

$(document).on('click', function (e) {
  if ($(e.target).closest('#imglookupbox').length === 0) {
    $('#imglookupbox + .dropdown .dropdown-menu').hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 30px;
  float: left;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.dropdown-menu li {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
}

.dropdown-menu li:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="imglookupbox" type="text" value="" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
<div class="dropdown">
  <ul id="Imageoptions" class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <img onclick='Findimage()' class='Img_Selection' src="DataBaseSetup/Images/ImageName" alt="no Image">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I noticed this when messing with the css and was about to update my question but this works grate thanks.